# Find all 100% event combinations in correlation matrix

Tags: python

I have a correlation matrix which correlated a list of events with themselves.
So, if the intersection between events A and B is 1, every time when A happens B also happens, etc. the typical correlation stuff.

And when an event G also correlates for 1 with A and B all three events always happen at the same time.

Now I tried for some time to figure out how to get a list containing all the event combinations that correlate for 1 with each element in their combination.

How do I get a list of all 100% dependent event combinations?

I managed to get the coordinates of all 1 vectors of the matrix and tried for some time to compare them with their spacial coordinates that would be expected in the matrix in case of 100% dependents but I am not quite figuring it out yet and I am wondering if there is an easier way.

I got the correlation matrix via pandas .corr(), resulting in a dataframe, which I then tranformed in a numpy array.
with a subset of a correlation matrix for example looking like this:

```
matrix = np.array([
[1, -0.5,   -0.5,   1,  1,  -0.5,   -0.5,   -0.5,   -0.5],
[-0.5,  1,  1,  -0.5,   -0.5,   1,  1,  1,  1], 
[-0.5,  1,  1,  -0.5,   -0.5,   1,  1,  1,  1],
[1, -0.5,   -0.5,   1,  1,  -0.5,   -0.5,   -0.5,   -0.5],  
[1, -0.5,   -0.5,   1,  1,  -0.5,   -0.5,   -0.5,   -0.5],  
[-0.5,  1,  1,  -0.5,   -0.5,   1,  1,  1,  1], 
[-0.5,  1,  1,  -0.5,   -0.5,   1,  1,  1,  1], 
[-0.5,  1,  1,  -0.5,   -0.5,   1,  1,  1,  1], 
[-0.5,  1,  1,  -0.5,   -0.5,   1,  1,  1,  1],
])
```

As seen in this example from the events, indice 0 to 8, with the indices 1,2,5,6,7 and 8 correlate with each other for 1 (100%), and so do indices 0, 3 and 4

as output i would like some sort of list, like

```
result = [
[1,2,5,6,7, 8],[0, 3, 4]
]
```

Comment: Could you share a (small) sample of an input matrix and the corresponding desired output? (Is the matrix a NumPy array? A Pandas DataFrame? A list of lists?)

Comment: added an example, also I got the correlation matrix from pandas .corr(). I can switch between numpy array and dataframe as much as i want. So, any solution whether for dataframe or numpy array is fine with me.

Comment: You could do a row at a time, doing `np.argwhere(matrhx[0] == 1)`

Comment: that would give me the locations of the 1s, which is not my problem. the thing I have difficulties with would be translating these coordinates into these packages of dendent indices.

Comment: no, wait, you are right. since the corr_matrix is diagonally mirrored by nature, I can just get the coordinates of the 1s of each row and put them in a list while discarding the duplicates...
I swear, since noon I had this nagging feeling in the back of my head, like the solution standing beside me and screaming at me...
thanks guys, solid help